How to select alternate or specific environments for pipeline status to be shown in the Operations Dashboard?
We are exploring the dashboards available in the GitLab UI to monitor the status of our project pipelines in a single place. We have five environments feature, develop, test, stage and production.
We have created an Operations dashboard and added some projects and it is by default displaying the pipeline status for develop environment.
However, we want the dashboard to display status for
develop and test
The GitLab UI does not provide any options to select the required environments. So, not sure how can we change them.  Could you please help.
Versions
GitLab Enterprise Edition 17.0.0
